# How do you make IIS consistent between environments?

Tags: iis, web-config, webserver

I have a website that is hosted on IIS.

I want to make sure that it's working exactly the same way on my local PC as on a production server.

There are two things in particular that I'm concerned about:

**IIS Extensions**: for example, I have used the [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension for IIS. It was installed on the server manually. How can I make sure that developers know to install it on their PCs? Is there some kind of manifest for IIS that would indicate that extension is required? Automatic installation would be beyond my wildest expectations :) Something that would work like `pacakge.json` for `npm`.

**Windows Features**: for example, I want to enable gzip for both static and dynamic content (`<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" />`). On my PC I didn't have `World Wide Web Services\Performance\Dynamic Content Compression` feature enabled, and IIS didn't alert me about this, it just pretended to be working as normal. What would be the best way to indicate that this is required as well?

Perhaps, I can add some powershell scripts that will enable features and install extensions before running IIS? Is there any standard or best practice around this?

Comment: PowerShell DSE might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/getting-started/wingettingstarted?view=powershell-7.1 But usually people keep their UAT server in sync with the production server, and might not do the same for developer desktops.

Comment: @LexLi looks like I can use it for windows feature management, nice! What about IIS extensions? As far as I understand, they are just installable programs, can I do that with DSC?

Comment: from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29105.installing-msi-packages-using-powershell-desired-state-configuration.aspx I can see that it's possible to install msi with DSC

Comment: @MaximMazurok Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @samwu not really. Our company guru said that we tried to use DSC, but it didn't meet all our needs. We use Ansible to manage linux servers, so maybe we could use it to manage windows servers as well. But for now, the best solution we could come up with is to migrate to Docker with Nginx, instead of using IIS.